# Passing Array of arrays to subroutine in Perl

Tags: perl

I'm trying to create a subroutine which will pass an array of arrays to a subroutine so commands can be run in different directories in parallel.

Basically, each first index is for each command-directory pair.  The second index has two variables: directory and the command itself.

For example,

```
my @commands;
$commands[0][0] = 'tmp1';#directory
$commands[0][1] = 'echo "ave Maria" > avemaria.txt';#command
```

however, I cannot figure out how to reference the data in a subroutine, I have tried every possible combination of "[]{}" I can think of in many different locations.  I've read the perl documentation in https://perldoc.perl.org/perldsc.html but can't see how it applies here.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict; use warnings; use Cwd;
my $TOP_DIRECTORY = getcwd();
local $SIG{__WARN__} = sub {#kill the program if there are any warnings
    my $message = shift;
    my $fail_filename = "$TOP_DIRECTORY/$0.FAIL";
    open my $fh, '>', $fail_filename or die "Can't write $fail_filename: $!";
    printf $fh ("$message @ %s\n", getcwd());
    close $fh;
    die "$message\n";
};#http://perlmaven.com/how-to-capture-and-save-warnings-in-perl

sub execute {
    my $command = shift;
    print "Executing Command: $command\n";
    if (system($command) != 0) {
        my $fail_filename = "$TOP_DIRECTORY/$0.fail";
        open my $fh, '>', $fail_filename or die "Can't write $fail_filename: $!";
        print $fh "$command failed.\n";
        close $fh;
        print "$command failed.\n";
        die;
    }
}

sub run_parallel {
    my $command_array_reference = shift;
    unless ((ref $command_array_reference) =~ m/ARRAY/) {
        print "run_parallel requires an array reference as input.\n";
        die;
    }
    use Parallel::ForkManager;
    my $manager = new Parallel::ForkManager(4);
    my $START_DIRECTORY = getwd();
    foreach my $command (0..scalar @{ $command_array_reference }-1) {
        $manager->start and next;
        my $dir = @$command_array_reference[$command][0];
        chdir $dir or die "Can't chdir to $dir: $!";
        execute( @$command_array_reference[$command][1] );
        chdir $START_DIRECTORY or die "Can't chdir to $START_DIRECTORY: $!";
        $manager->finish;
    }
    $manager->wait_all_children;#necessary after all lists
}

my @commands;

$commands[0][0] = 'tmp1';#directory
$commands[0][1] = 'echo "ave Maria" > aveMaria.txt';#command

$commands[1][0] = 'tmp2';#directory
$commands[1][1] = 'echo "IN HOC SIGNO VINCES" > xp.txt';#command

run_parallel(\@commands);
```

this particular configuration produces the error

```
703404669@ssxfisctimga004:~/Scripts$ perl parallelForkManager_dir.pl
syntax error at parallelForkManager_dir.pl line 38, near "]["
Global symbol "$dir" requires explicit package name at parallelForkManager_dir.pl line 39.
Global symbol "$dir" requires explicit package name at parallelForkManager_dir.pl line 39.
syntax error at parallelForkManager_dir.pl line 40, near "]["
Execution of parallelForkManager_dir.pl aborted due to compilation errors.
```

how can I read the directory-command pairs in the subroutine?

Comment: You seem to be learning with several different tutorials, one of them being Gabor's PerlMaven. That's great. But right now your style gives away your strategy, and your code has a lot of issues. If you want, feel free to post it in the Perl tag on [codereview.se] and someone will take a look and give you some code-style advice, and maybe something about your strategy too. You should also start reading the error messages. Being exact is a big part of programming, and usually when there's an error, the message is useful. :)

Comment: I endorse what **simbabque** has said. I think you would learn a lot by posting your *working* code on [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) and allowing us to critique it. I often combine my own answers with a review of the OP's code, but that is strictly off-topic, and it is much better if you ask for the review yourself.

Comment: @Borodin there you go: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/182010/23233

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are in doubt about a data structure, [Data::Dumper](https://metacpan.org/pod/Data::Dumper) is your friend.

```
use Data::Dumper;

# with your @commands
print Dumper \@commands;
```

This prints

```
$VAR1 = [
      [
        'tmp1',
        'echo "ave Maria" > aveMaria.txt'
      ],
      [
        'tmp2',
        'echo "IN HOC SIGNO VINCES" > xp.txt'
      ]
    ];
```

Now we know that there is an array reference with array references inside. The first level of reference is the backslash in your `\@commands`. It creates a reference to the array. The second reference is each array ref inside that.

In Perl, you cannot have an array inside an array, only references to arrays. The way you are assigning them is correct short-hand, but probably confused you.

```
$commands[0][0]   = 'tmp1';
$commands[0]->[0] = 'tmp1'; # equivalent
```

The `->` is the dereference operator. It's not required for a multi-dimensional data structure, because they are always references beyond the first

Now in your sub you've got:

```
my $command_array_reference = \@commands;
```

To get to the values, use the arrows. You can omit most of them, but the first one is required.

```
my $dir = $command_array_reference->[0]->[0];
my $cmd = $command_array_reference->[0]->[1];
```

If you want to get the whole thing as a list, dereference the first level like this, which tells Perl that what's inside of `$foo->[0]` is an array ref:

```
my ($dir, $cmd) = @{ $command_array_reference->[0] };
```

---

I suggest you take a look at [perlreftut](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlreftut.html), [perlref](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlref.html) and maybe [perllol](http://perldoc.perl.org/perllol.html).

Comment: I much prefer [`Data::Dump`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Data::Dump). The output is far more readable, and it exports `dd`, so `print Dumper \@commands` becomes `dd \@commands`. The  only downside is that it's non-core.

Comment: I hope my edit's okay? I fixed a typo and then went on to `s/needed/required/`, just because *required* is absolute whereas *need* may be simply a life/death thing.

Comment: @Borodin yeah, that's fine, thanks. I know you do, and you know I prefer Data::Printer. ;) But I figured the out-of-the-box solution is fine here.

Comment: Actually I wasn't really aware that you preferred `Data::Printer`. To be honest I loathe it because it's yet another data language and there's nothing that compiles it, and if I want syntax highlighting then I'll put it in a highlighting window. But then **Sinan Ünür** prefers non-JSON YAML, which I can't read either, so each to his own I guess! (I guess I also prefer `Data::Dump` because it's written by **Gisle Aas** who can do no wrong in my eyes!)

Comment: @Borodin I haven't met **Garu** yet, but I once confused **GUGOD** in person for him. The idea of Data::Printer is that it's not a portable format, but purely for human consumption. I like that. It does useful things, like sorting, introspecting objects, where it knows the methods and inheritance, and you can use it for pass-through debugging. I'm seeing more of YAML recently, also because our new regular **Tinita** is a friend and she's actively working on the YAML spec, so she cannot shut up about it. :) But in general, I try to pick the debugging tools in answers by skill of OP.